# Whats the point of traversing through the linked list to get a value, I could get it directly right?

Tags: c

Why do we even need to traverse through the list, though I'm getting the value of the last element if I do `printf("%d", end->value)` as in line 40, instead of traversing through each and every element?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void print(struct node *top) {
    while (top != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", top->value);
        top = top->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *second;
    struct node *end;

    head = NULL;
    second = NULL;
    end = NULL;

    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    end = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->value = 5;
    head->next = second;

    second->value = 9;
    second->next = end;

    end->value = 10;
    end->next = NULL;

    printf("%d\n", end->value ); /*I m directly getting the output as 10, 
 whats the use of traversing through the list to get the same value? */

    print(head); /*this is the use of the function to traverse through the  
                    list*/
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what is the point of doing something in your own code? You have pointers to each one of the nodes, so there is no point in having linked list at all for this case, if you ask me.

Comment: If you are maintaining a pointer to the last node, and you want to print the value of the last node, then there is *no* point in traversing the list.  But if you were *not* keeping a pointer to the last node, which is not uncommon, then traversing the list would be the only way to find it.

Comment: the best way to avoid to traverse the tree ... is to not use a tree but an array allowing you to get any nth# value directly ;-) List have advantages and disadvantages, like any other kinds of collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there is no downside to directly get the value, but in many other cases you will use some function to create the new nodes and more often than not you will only have one pointer that directly point to a node (usually the head).
So while here it is not wrong to directly grab the value, in most cases, there isn't the option to grab the value and you will need to traverse if you want to get the values